# effect on order of argument of complex number

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

If $arg(x,y)<arg(x',y')$. What will be relation bewteen $arg(2x, y)$ and $arg(2x', y')$.

Where range of $arg$ is taken in $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: **Hint** The map $(x, y) \mapsto (2 x, y)$ is an orientation-preserving (real) linear transformation preserving the branch cut $\{\arg z = 0\}$.

Comment: Actually I am trying to prove this fact only that this orientation preserving map has property mentioned above @Travis

Comment: For a (real) linear map to have the properties I mentioned, it must the preserve orientation of $\Bbb R^2$ and fix the $x$-axis and the orientation of the $x$-axis$. What constraints does these conditions impose on $(x, y) \mapsto (a x + b y, c x + d y)$?

Comment: And would be so? @Travis